# VB.net saving input into function

Tags: vb.net, function, project

Recently I've started working on project VB for my As computing class, and after few painful hours of vb coding i hit the solid brick wall. Which looks like this

```
Private Function store(ByVal opt As Integer, ByVal inp As String, ByVal q As String) As String
        Dim na_me(20), amount(20), num1 As String
        Select Case opt
            Case 0
                na_me(num1) += inp
                amount(num1) += q
                num1 += 1
                Return "1"
            Case 1
                For Each Str As String In na_me
                    Console.WriteLine(Str)
                Next
                Return "1"
            Case 2
                num1 = 0
                Return "1"
            Case Else
                Return "0"
        End Select
    End Function
```

Every time argument 1 is called it just returns blank screen instead of array full of data.
This function was designed to hold and save any data passed through function call, and then save it into array. and once 1 was passed as opt argument then print out all data held in arrays. I know this is a noob question but i've never used vb.net before and i'm only doing it at school.

Here's rest of the code http://pastebin.com/nWxvx9pz

Comment: You are recreating your arrays every time you run your function try declaring them as static

Comment: Also, `num1` should be static and should be an integer, not a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternatively you could do something like this and use strongly typed collections/properties.

If you did need to get these as an array all you would need to is MyStoredValues.ToArray()

```
Module Module1


    Private na_me As List(Of String)
    Public Property MyStoredValues() As List(Of String)
        Get
            If na_me Is Nothing Then
                na_me = New List(Of String)
            End If
            Return na_me
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As List(Of String))
            na_me = value
        End Set
    End Property


    Private amount As List(Of String)
    Public Property MyAmount() As List(Of String)
        Get
            If amount Is Nothing Then
                amount = New List(Of String)
            End If
            Return amount
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As List(Of String))
            amount = value
        End Set
    End Property



    Sub Main()
        store(0, "TEST TEST TEST", "10.23")
        store(0, "TEST2 TEST2 TEST2", "11.33")
        store(1, "", "")
        Console.ReadKey()
    End Sub
    Private Function store(ByVal opt As Integer, ByVal inp As String, ByVal q As String) As Boolean

        Select Case opt
            Case 0
                MyStoredValues.Add(inp)
                MyAmount.Add(q)

                Return True
            Case 1
                For Each Str As String In MyStoredValues
                    Console.WriteLine(Str)
                Next
                Return True

            Case Else
                Return False
        End Select
    End Function
End Module
```

Comment: Thank you very much for all your answers, but unfortunately i'm not that advanced in vb.net yet, but declaring variables in module instead of sub Main seemed to work just fine. But anyway thanks for all answers you guys saved my life :)

Answer (score 0):

declare ALL your variables at the module level above the comments in your program.
remove them from where they are now once you have done that.
Show the selection of the items being sold as a catlogue at the top of the sales screen.

something like...

```
        Do
        Console.Clear()
        Console.WriteLine("CATALOGUE" & Chr(13) & Chr(13))
        Console.WriteLine("Id     Name                   Price" & Chr(13))
        Console.WriteLine("=======================================" & Chr(13))
        For num = 0 To 11
            Console.WriteLine(Format(num, "00") & "   " & product(num) & " " & price(num) & Chr(13))
        Next
        Console.WriteLine("=======================================" & Chr(13))
        Console.WriteLine(Chr(13))
```

Dont forget NUM1 is an integer and not a string as the other member pointed out.

To display the Qunatity in your STORE procedure add a variable called num2 and code it as follows...

```
            Case 1
            Console.WriteLine("Your Selection" & Chr(13))
            For num2 = 0 To UBound(na_me) - 1
                Console.WriteLine(na_me(num2) & "   " & amount(num2) & Chr(13))
            Next
```

By using the UBOUND(array-name-here) statment you will find the maximum number of array elements in the array currently and you will also be able to access the AMOUNT() array via the NUM2 variable

Answer (score 0):

```
Try
            Dim con As New OleDbConnection
            Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand
            Dim ads As OleDbDataReader
            Dim ads1 As OleDbDataReader
            Dim dr As OleDbDataReader
             sql = "select joindate from Employee where Empcode='" & empid & "'"
                    cmd = New OleDbCommand(sql, con)
                    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
           While dr.Read
                        If dr(0) > dtpdate.Value Then
                            MsgBox("Can't Pay advance!  Joined only on " & Format(dr(0), "dd-MMM-yyyy") & "")
                            Exit Sub
                        End If
                    End While
                    dr.Close()
                    cmd.CommandText = "insert into advance (Date,Empid,Amount,Remark,CompanyId,Confir)values('" & Format(dtpdate.Value, "dd/MMM/yyyy") & "','" & empid & "'," & txtamt.Text & ",'" & txtremark.Text & "'," & CompanyCode & ",'NO')"
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
 End Sub
```